# get all the lines from second file matching with values of a specific column in the first file

Tags: text-processing

I have two files:

first file:

```
ab34,ax,55,gt
ab46,56,thy,ix
ab34,tg,47,xy
at87,kl,89,th
ab46,ut,87,er
```

second file:

```
x1,ab34,78,got
wq,at87,100,op
90,ab46,la,gf
```

expected result:

```
ab34,ax,55,gt,x1,ab34,78,got
ab46,56,thy,ix,90,ab46,la,gf
ab34,tg,47,xy,x1,ab34,78,got
at87,kl,89,th,wq,at87,100,op
ab46,ut,87,er,90,ab46,la,gf
```

I want to grep lines in the second file based on the values in first column of the first file. The ideal output would be printing the first file with the lines that match from the second file. I write simple unix commands but this one is a bit trickier for me, apparently needs a loop function.

Comment: Do you really want to "grep" the second file - or match first file column 1 against second file column 2?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like idea case for UNIX commands, you need to sort first:

```
cat 1|sort > 1.sort
cat 2|sort -t, -k2  > 2.sort
join -t, -2 2 1.sort 2.sort
```

Did I just do you homework?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a lot of assumptions about what you actually want, but this produces your desired sample output.  So perhaps my interpretation of the question is correct:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' FS=, OFS=, file2 file1
```